# wxPython でフォーム(ウインドウ)間の値の受け渡し

Tags: python

wxPython で「次へ」「戻る」でフォーム(ウインドウ)を変えていくプログラムを作っています。
移動元のフォームで指定した値を移動先で参照したいです。どのようにやればいいでしょうか。

やりたいことは以下のような感じです。

**移動元フォーム**

```
def button_modify_click(self, event):
    dlg = frmModify.frmModify()
    global room_num
    room_num = u"104"
    dlg.Show()
    self.Close(True)
    return True
```

**移動先フォーム**

```
class frmModify(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        global room_num
        (中略)
        self.text_room_no = wx.TextCtrl(pRoom, wx.ID_ANY, room_num, size = (640, 64))
```

どうぞよろしくご教示のほどお願いします。

Comment: wxは詳しくありませんが、プロパティを移動先フォームに追加して、移動元でセットしてから`Show`するのはいかがでしょう？Window間で値の更新を反映したいなら`Bind`する手もあります。ところでwxではglobalをWindow間で共有してもスレッドセーフですか？

Comment: def button_modify_click(self, event):
  dlg = frmModify.frmModify()
  dlg.room_name = u"104"
  dlg.Show()
  self.Close(True)
  return True
-----
class frmModify(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(self):
  room_name = ""
  (中略)
       self.text_room_no = wx.TextCtrl(pRoom, wx.ID_ANY, room_name, size = (640, 64))
-----
だめでした。移動先に room_name の値を渡せませんでした。

Comment: `wx.TextCtrl(pRoom, wx.ID_ANY, self.room_name, size = (640, 64))`ですね

Comment: def __init__(self): self.room_name = "" (中略) self.text_room_no = wx.TextCtrl(pRoom, wx.ID_ANY, self.room_name, size = (640, 64))
-----
だめでした。

Comment: self.room_name = ""としているのだから当然です。その行まで直しましょうとは書いていません。もう少しPythonを勉強したほうがいいですね。

Comment: python をやりだして一週間なので…、大変申し訳ありません。
移動先に
def ImportRoomNum(self, room_num):
    self.text_room_no.SetLabel(room_num)
を作って、
移動元から
  dlg = frmModify.frmModify()
  dlg.ImportRoomNum(u"104")
  dlg.Show()
でデータを受け渡せました。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

プロパティを移動先フォームに追加して、移動元でセットしてからShowするのはいかがでしょう？
Window間で値の更新を反映したいならBindする手もあります。

下記は関数で値を渡すサンプルコードです。

```
import wx

class frmModify(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "遷移先")
        self.SetSize((680, 80))
        pRoom = wx.Panel(self)
        
        self.text_room_no = wx.TextCtrl(pRoom, wx.ID_ANY, size = (640, 64))

    # 値を渡す関数
    def ImportRoomNum(self, room_num):
        self.text_room_no.SetValue(room_num + "に送られました。")

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        self.SetSize((60, 120))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        
        self.room_name = "5号室"
        
        self.text_room = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.room_name, pos=(10,40), size = (100,25))
        self.button_modify = wx.Button(panel, label="modify", pos=(10,10), size=(100,25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_modify_click, self.button_modify)
        
        self.Show(True)

    def button_modify_click(self, event):
        dlg = frmModify()
        dlg.ImportRoomNum(self.text_room.GetValue()) # フォーム(ウインドウ)間の値の受け渡し
        dlg.Show()
    
    def close(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def printer(self, event):
        print("Button2")
        
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "遷移元")
app.MainLoop()
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @MaFengLing さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19537/wxpython-%e3%81%a7%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%82%a6%e9%96%93%e3%81%ae%e5%80%a4%e3%81%ae%e5%8f%97%e3%81%91%e6%b8%a1%e3%81%97#comment18167_19537)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>